# Dynamic Route Params from Form Submit

Tags: dynamic, parameters, svelte, sveltekit

I have a form that is passing a string to a search page that uses that string to query an API and display results. When I submit the form, the URL is `x/search/string?slug=string`. I am looking for a way to keep the URL cleaner and have it be `x/search/string`.

My form code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    let slug = '';
</script>

<form action={`search/${slug}`}>
    <input bind:value={slug} name="slug" type="text" />
    <button type="submit" />
</form>
```

My `+page.server.ts` code:

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({fetch, params}) =>{

  const fetchSearchResults = async (slug:string) => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=${slug}`)
    const data = await res.json();
    return {data};
  }
  return {
    results: fetchSearchResults(params.slug)
  }
}
```

The URL `x/search/string?slug=string` provides the same results as `x/search/string` but I am positive I am doing something wrong. Any help or links to some examples that would help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Btw, attributes like  ``action={`search/${slug}`}`` can be simplified to `action="search/{slug}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input in the form is sent as part of the form request, for GET that results in query parameters.

There are multiple options, e.g. remove the `name` attribute.

You could also move the element out of the form, but I would not recommend that, as it breaks things like being able to press Enter to submit the form.